# How to set strike line of text view with red color in Android

Tags: android

Using this code I am able to display text view with strike to textView :

```
   holder.discounttext.setText("MRP " + rupee + discountcost);
            holder.discounttext.setPaintFlags(holder.discounttext.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

This is my Current Screen :[image]

Desire Screen:

[image]

Please tell me how to set  strike color with red?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439860/how-to-change-color-of-a-strikethrough-in-android

Answer (score 7):

Make a custom TextView

```
    class CustomTextView extends TextView {
            public Paint paint;
            public boolean addStrike = false;
    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
        public CustomTextView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            init(context);
        }

        public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            init(context);
        }

        private void init(Context context) {
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 1);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            if (addStrike) {
                canvas.drawLine(0, getHeight() / 2, getWidth(),
                        getHeight() / 2, paint);
            }
        }

    }
```

for adding stoke you can call

```
myCustomTextView.addStrike = true;
myCustomTextView.invalidate();
```

and for removing strike you just call

```
myCustomTextView.addStrike = false;
myCustomTextView.invalidate();
```

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/38rtewW4JY8RggsgYF52iAP  i have sue this code when i am running then this exception coming http://paste.ofcode.org/zijYBka9uVrcSEJXkLp6hw  please check where am doing wrong

Comment: i thing your log showing an error in your custom adapter.in getView()

Comment: yes but why this Error coming when i call customtextview in Simple textview no Exception coming

Comment: do you get a preview of custom text view.i not ,your parent layout will be missing some attributes

Comment: My Code is Ok na Please check

Comment: I have updated my class try it again..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97933/discussion-between-akhil-jayakumar-and-research-development).

Comment: Still Error coming canvas.drawLine(0, getHeight() / 2, getWidth(),
                        getHeight() / 2, paint);  here

Comment: any Suggestion for this Error ?

Comment: He is missing a call to init() in the first method

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to use Drawable. **The idea is to create a line drawable, and then set the background of TextView with this drawable.** Let the Drawable file be line.xml

```
<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape android:shape="line">
        <stroke android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#ffffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

This is the drawable for the line with red color, and 2dp width. [Alter it according to your requirements]

Then on the TextView, set the line.xml **drawable as background.**

```
holder.discounttext.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.line));
```

The output will be

[image]

Comment: No good for multiline textview.

Comment: Probably better to use SpannableStringBuilder and StrikethroughSpan, might be more flexible approach

Answer (score 0):

A couple of solutions:

- subclass textview and draw your own strike through. See [create different color strike through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237509/create-different-color-strike-through).
- overlay another view on top of it.

Comment: can u post me Custom Class Implmentaion ?